# What can a Gabbai do if no one wants to Daven from the Amud?

Tags: tefilla, chazzan-prayer-leader, gabbai

As a Gabbai Sheni I have noticed that often the Gabbai has a difficult time getting someone to daven from the Amud. Some Shuls have paid Chazonim, yet others can not afford that. What can a Gabbai do in order to get people to be willing to Daven from the Amud?

Comment: Why can't he daven himself?

Comment: Pay them. |||||

Comment: The Gabbai Davened last night, last week, and two weeks ago. How often does he have to Daven himself?

Comment: Ask the rabbi to speak about how people don't need to be [_that_ humble](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18794/5).

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18794/3

Answer (score 7):

I was talking to a friend of mine today about this question and he told me that recently he was in a Shul and no one wanted to Daven Musaf for the Amud. The Gabai has already Davened Shacharis and read the Kriyas HaTorah. So the Gabai made a loud announcement "Good Shabbos - Thanks for all of you joining with our Minyan. I am leaving now and will come back once someone goes to Daven Musaf" and he went out of the Shul. Within a minute someone went up to Daven.

Comment: +1. Similarly, I've seen a _gabay_ ask around, and, when no one accepted the role, simply stop asking and take his place.

Comment: In some shuls, it is a game of chicken. Everyone wants that someone should  daven mussaf so they can get home. It's just a matter of keeping calm and waiting. I suggest taking a sefer and learning.

Answer (score 6):

I would arrange for a chazan ahead of time, not right before davening. You probably know who the good chazanim are, so simply ask them a few days in advance and make a schedule (for yourself).