# Should one volunteer to be shliach tzibbur if no one else has gone up?

Tags: tefilla

I am aware that Poskim have mentioned it’s appropriate to at first turn down the offer to lead the Tefillah. However, if time for Minyan has started and no one has gone up to lead, is it proper or improper to volunteer and head right on up?

Comment: וּבְמָקוֹם שֶׁאֵין אֲנָשִׁים, הִשְׁתַּדֵּל לִהְיוֹת אִישׁ

Comment: Yes, *tircha de'tziburah*.

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18794/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18796/759