# Why didn't Joshua appoint a leader after him?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, death, joshua--book-of, shoftim--book-of

When Joshua dies, he doesn't (at least not explicitly in Joshua 24 or Judges 1) appoint a spiritual or military leader after him.

Joshua was appointed by Moses ([Numbers 27:15-23](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.27.15-23?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) and that appears to have served the Israelites well in conquering the land of Israel. Why doesn't Joshua do the same for the next generation?

Comment: sorta similar http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28277/why-did-nobody-succeed-the-lubavitcher-rebbe/28427#comment67757_28277

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for the question (+1)! You might want to consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features. Hope to see you around!

Answer (score 2):

From [Hidabroot](http://www.hidabroot.org/he/question/28594). Rabbi Menashe Yisrael explains that Yehoshua was compared to the moon, however the Shoftim after him were compared to the stars. Just like stars do not get their light from the moon, or from each other, so too Yehoshua did not shine a light upon a new leader.

> שאילתך, היה מקום לשאול, גם בנוגע לתקופת השופטים, למה לא התנבאה דבורה
>   למי למסור את ההנגה אחריה, ונצרך לשלוח אחר כך מלאך מיוחד לגדעון שיקבל
>   את ההנהגה. והביאור בזה על פי הקבלה הוא כך, ההנהגה השתלשלה ממשה שקיבל
>   תורה מהר סיני ליהושע תלמידו. ואחר כך עמדו לעם ישראל שנים עשרה שופטים
>   צדיקים [עתניאל, אהוד, שמגר, דבורה, גדעון, תולע, יאיר, יפתח, אבצן,
>   אילון, עבדון, שמשון]. משה רבינו הוא נגד בחינת השמש, ויהושע הוא מכוון
>   נגד הלבנה, וכלשון חז"ל פני משה כפני חמה ופני יהושע כפני לבנה, וכמו
>   שהלבנה מקבלת את האור שלה מהשמש כך משה רבינו הסמיך את יהושע בצו אלוקי.
>
> לעומת זאת השופטים הם בבחינת הכוכבים, ולפי הקבלה ישנן יב כוכבים [לא
>   מדובר על מניין הכוכבים בשמים אלא בבחינתם העליונה, וכפי שיוסף ראה בחלמו
>   את השבטים בדמות כוכבים משתחוים לו, וכפי שיש י"ב שבטים כך יש לנגדם י"ב
>   צירופי כוכבים - מזלות] כמניין שבטי ישראל, ולכן כמו שהכוכבים לא מקבלים
>   את האור שלהם מהשמש או הירח ולא זה מזה, כך לא נסמכו השופטים מיהושע ולא
>   שופט משופט

Comment: That sounds like an allegory to but not a reason for the situation. It probably *is* a reason for the situation (inasmuch as he says "והביאור בזה על פי הקבלה" which means doubtless that there's more to it than what he writes), but the part he writes doesn't look like a reason.